# Stashnotifier Jenkins plugin

Tags: jenkins, github, jenkins-pipeline

I want to use stashnotifier plugin for my pipeline
Do I need to install anything in git side ?
What should be the value of the property stash root URI in the configuration?

Comment: You just need to configure plugin with Bitbucket (stash) - connection info, credentials, project key, ...No change in Bitbucket itself AFAIK. See [plugin pipeline docs](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/stashNotifier/)

Comment: Thanks for quick reply . I configured my github connection info, I am not using bitbucket. Maybe this is my problem?